# Check if a node is in the path of a node for a directed graph

Tags: c++, c, data-structures, graph, llvm

I have a directed graph. I want to know if a node N is always in path of an upper node T. The way I check it is by starting from the entry node and perform a depth first search. If in any path it is seen that node N is encountered before node T, it is  assumed its not always in its path.

As an example, in the attached image, the entry node is `entry_0_CC_FC`, upper Node is `if_end_0_CC_FC` and node N is `land.lhs.true26_0_CC_FC`.

However I am seeing that my algorithm is stuck in an infinite loop. Either its taking too much time, or stuck, I am not sure. There are 119 blocks in this graph by the way. Here is the code. Could you see any problem which can make it stuck in infinite loop.

```
void CheckIfNotAlwaysInPath(bool& violation, BasicBlock* BS, 
  BasicBlock* BT, BasicBlock* BN, set<BasicBlock*> visited)
{
    int i;

    // If already visited
    if ( visited.find( BS ) != visited.end() ) // If already had visited
        return;

    visited.insert(BS);

    if ( BS == BN )
    {
        if ( visited.find( BT ) == visited.end() )
            violation = true;
        return;
    }

    if ( isa<ReturnInst>(BS->getTerminator()) )
        return;
    if ( BS->getTerminator()->getNumSuccessors() == 0 )
        return;


    for( i = 0; i < BS->getTerminator()->getNumSuccessors(); i++ )
    {
        if ( visited.find( BS->getTerminator()->getSuccessor(i) ) == visited.end() )
            CheckIfNotAlwaysInPath(violation, BS->getTerminator()->getSuccessor(i), BT, BN, visited);
    }
}
```

[image].

Comment: The graph is a bit big, at least for my part I can't recognize a thing in this graph, would you mind scaling it so it's less pixelized?

Comment: Do you think its too big and takes too much time to compute for every path

Comment: First time a *screenshot* fails the "minimal, complete example" requirement!

Comment: Kerrek SB: What do you mean by "fails the minimal complete example requirement"?

Comment: No, I was trying to say that I'm having a hard time recognizing the characters of the blocks:)

Comment: First, pass visited by reference, not by value - it copies the set<> on each call, it's memory and performance penalty. Second, what is BB and BC? They are not defined in the code.

Comment: Rost: I deliberately pass it by value, because each path is a different path and we need to check visited separately for each path. Concerning BB and BC, I have corrected the code now.

Answer (score 0):

Check for feedbacks in the graph. Then check the referring function blocks / state machine in the code.
The upper part of the diagram until if.end531_0_CC_FC should be alright.
Afterwards the for.body blocks or the for.cond675.loopexit_0_cc_FC might be error prone ... or some of the other loopbacks.

My first guess would be the loopback from for.cond675.loopexit_0_cc_FC to for.body.688.lr.ph_0_CC_FC though.

Comment: But I make sure, we don't loop back. The visited set is for that purpose. Do you think I can still have a loopback?

Comment: Basically for for.cond675, for.body688 is a successor. Now since for.body688 is already in the visited set (since we encountered it before), the algorithm will not visit it once more. In this way, loopbacks are not parsed again.